# C# Expression class method extension, making string comparison case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, expression, string-comparison

This is my Expression extension method that adds `InBetweenStr` functionality to [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) (`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`) class. However, I want to imply to string comparison to ignore case so I modified `StringComparisonExpression` and added third argument: `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. But of course code does not work and throws an exception saying that: "Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method `Int32 Compare(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)`".

So I am wondering is there an elegant way to make string comparison case insensitive other than passing `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` as a third argument to `string.Compare` from `Expression.Call`

Code:

```
// for InBetweenStr and NotInBetweenStr
public static Expression<Func<int>> StringComparisonExpression = () => string.Compare(null, null);
public static MethodInfo StringComparisonExpressionhMethodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression) StringComparisonExpression.Body).Method;


public static Expression InBetweenStr(this Expression value, Expression lowerBound, Expression upperBound)
{
    // zero constant expression
    var zeroExpr = Expression.Constant(0);

    return Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression.Call(StringComparisonExpressionhMethodInfo, value, lowerBound), zeroExpr),
        Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression.Call(StringComparisonExpressionhMethodInfo, value, upperBound), zeroExpr)
    );
}
```

Modified `StringComparisonExpression` which results in exception:

```
public static Expression<Func<int>> StringComparisonExpression = () => string.Compare(null, null, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `MethodInfo` of the three-argument `string.Compare` method like this:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo StringComparisonExpressionMethodInfo =
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Compare", new Type[] {
        typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison)
    });
```

With this `MethodInfo` in place you can call the method with a third parameter:

```
var ignoreCase = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
return Expression.AndAlso(
    Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression.Call(StringComparisonExpressionMethodInfo, value, lowerBound, ignoreCase), zeroExpr),
    Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression.Call(StringComparisonExpressionMethodInfo, value, upperBound, ignoreCase), zeroExpr)
);
```

Since you are passing a constant for the third parameter, make `ignoreCase` constant expression the same way you made `zeroExpr`.